# Swap background image multiple times in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x

I am making a story-based 2D game using Cocos2d-x, and I need to switch the background sprite, which is a sprite the is taking the entire resolution of the frame, multiple times during the game. How can I do this ??

I think I should load all the background images to a texture cache of some sort at the beginning and then just swap them, but I don't really know how to do that.

I'd really appreciate some code snippets for Cocos2d-x 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. Here it is for future reference:

```
    void GameLayer::setNewSpriteTexture(Sprite* sprite, Texture2D* newTex) {

    Rect rect = Rect::ZERO;
    rect.size = newTex->getContentSize();
    sprite->setTexture(newTex);
    sprite->setTextureRect(rect, false, rect.size); 
}
```

and every used texture has to be pre-loaded to the texture cache as follows:

```
_menuTexture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("menu.png");
```

Comment: if image is large, suggest you consider using TextureCache->addImageAsync